# How to embed ICC profile in image in c++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, image, icc

I'm looking for a standard way to embed an ICC profile into an image. At the moment my image type is PNG. I'm trying NOT to use any 3rd party software.

Any help or pointers are appreciated

Comment: Do you consider libpng http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html 3rd party? It is the official reference library and it has functions for this.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm just pointing to an API.  I believe you're looking for Windows Imaging Component:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654(v=vs.85).aspx